# Getting all the Contracts created at Opensea and Rarible

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, erc-721, nft

I want to pull the number of NFT contracts created on opensea and rarible. I checked opensea API documentation and it seems like you can pass a range token ID's in this case I was wondering what would be the range If I want to include them all. :
https://docs.opensea.io/reference#retrieving-asset-events

Does anybody know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The number of returned NFT assets is approximately 50

You should do a paging query